# improving the "vote to close" usability window

Tags: discussion, usability

My proposal is just from a **usability** point of view. The current "vote to close" window is as follows:

[image: current vote to close window]

Here the proposed one:

[image: proposed vote to close window]

To explain:

- action buttons should be near each other and not at both sides of a window
- closing "X" button is redundant (and often times is at the top right anyway)
- make uniform action buttons

  What do you think guys?

Comment: `action buttons should be near each other and not at both sides of a window` Why?

Comment: @Bobby for the same reason your car has volume buttons and other audio controls near each other. Would you like the bass to be controlled from under the visor or from the side of the seat? In other words, I shouldn't have to fumble around the UI depending on which action I want to take.

Comment: I hate it when links are used like that. Links are supposed to take you places. Buttons are better for doing stuff. Having "Cancel" be a link is OK because it takes you back to where you were, but "Vote to Close" is definitely an action and hence it should be a button.

Comment: I like having opposite actions far apart. Less risk of clicking the wrong action. Leave the window alone.

Comment: I totally agree with @AnthonyPegram, having different actions on different sides (LTR people, Left back/undo, Right forward/ok) seems to me like a good idea (Gnome2 does have that layout, too). The possibility of a wrong click is minimized. But maybe we should have that discussion on UX?

Comment: @Bobby there are studies that show that it is easier for a user to find all the commands in a window in the same physical place. One of the many references on the subject: http://sixrevisions.com/usabilityaccessibility/improving-usability-with-fitts-law/

Comment: If you keep downvoting like that I'll soon go to hell :)

Comment: This is wrong in so many ways, I don't even know where to start. But it catches my eye you suggest the close button is redundant. Um, no? There's not going to be one in the top right (or left) because this is not a new browser window. It's a *pop-up* window. You have to provide your own close button. (Also, note that [downvotes are different on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq/#vote-differences). You might be going to hell, but it won't be because of them.)

Comment: "What do you think guys?"  *downvotealanche* OMGWTFDOWNVOTES

Comment: You know, I never even noticed the "cancel" before.  I always canceled out of the dialog by using the close "X" in the top left corner.

Comment: Also, obligatory: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/03/the-opposite-of-fitts-law.html

Comment: @David that's because you're not blind, I guess. Accessibility anyone?

Answer (score 11):

The problem with the suggested layout is that when I want to carry out the action I have to read both of the links to get the idea of what they do. If the other is a button and the other is a link, I can just click on the button without reading it because by now I know its general location and what it does. Having to cancel the action is much more rare and it's ok if it's not as prominent - but even cancelling isn't a problem now, because *there's a big X that does it on the top left corner*.

Comparison to audio controls on a radio doesn't apply well, I think. If you turn the bass control instead of volume control, no harm done, but there's a reason why the power switch is often as far away from the other controls as possible.

Comment: +1 for the powercontrol argument.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the `X` is in the correct place,

is looking like one more option the cancel option. If you see is in the same align as the rest radio buttons, and looks like radio button.

Also the eye is start looking from start left up, and end down right, correct follow path to view the full window content.

Some windows must be a little different to not click mechanical with out thinking.

Comment: close is not a radio button, semantically. it means: no, sorry, do nothing.

Comment: @vulkanino Is not radio button of course, but is a part of the options you have. Is like one of the options you have.